# Java library for code analysis

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any Java library, that can help in building [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from the specified java source file and vice versa (generate code from the ASTree object)? I need something like [this](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php), but with an API, allowing to access the generated tree programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything's already available within the Eclipse core.
[Here's a page](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html#sec-parsing-a-source-file) with a small example of how to use `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser` to create your desired AST datastructure.